# IS there any way to know total number of pipelines in Gitlab without using the API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

I am trying to decide which Gitlab tier to move to. I have an almost 3 years old Gitlab-ce. I want to test whether I need 2000 CI pipeline **minutes** or 10000 (Bronze and Silver tiers). What I learned so far, is that it needs some scripting along with Gitlab API but I want to make sure I am not overdoing it here in case that I can get these infos somewhere else, e.g. admin area.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `admin area` > `jobs`, there is `Pipeline` information in the third column. You can see there the pipeline ID, which is incremented for each new pipeline :

[image]

In my case, I ran 11715 pipelines since the start of my gitlab-ce instance.

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. Anyway what I need is calculating minutes since this is the quota defined in Gitlab.com tiers